# Why does my Javascript audio not work after I refresh a page?

Tags: javascript, audio, promise

I have an audio object in my javascript and a call to the play function. It works fine when the I go to the page for the first time or go there through a link from one of my other pages, BUT when I'm on the page with the audio and just want to refresh the page I get audio errors,

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException
```

I have read a post about someone whose audio only works after they refresh it a few times (the opposite of my problem). And I've read about that error. But all I'm trying to do is refresh the page and have things work like they worked the first time.

```
console.log("playing test sound");
let test_sound = new Audio('/static/audio/to-the-point.mp3');
test_sound.play();
```

This works when I first go to the page, but then gives me that error when I refresh it and the audio doesn't work no matter how many more times I refresh... any ideas?

EDIT: upon playing around with it more, the times that the audio gets the error is very inconsistent upon refreshing. Sometimes, the refresh is fine other times it just gets an error. Once it gets the error though, subsequent refreshes also get it. Maybe it's my chrome browser or mac computer?

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException` has nothing to do with your `Audio`. The script is dying for another reason. It could be anything really. It's impossible to tell without looking at the full code. The snippet you added in your question is of course correct.

Comment: This happens because playing audio is not allowed without a user interaction on the page. Once a user interaction has happened, audio will be allowed to play. Sometimes even when you reload the page (and sometimes not... I don’t know why that is :)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the code I posted is the code that I'm talking about. Nothing more...

Comment: @Kokodoko I'm wondering if you could elaborate on that because that seems consistent with my findings. So the audio can't start playing unless the user has interacted with the page? This would explain why it works when I come from another page and not work when I just refresh. But that seems like a crazy thing. Is there anyway to get audio to play when the page refreshes?

Answer (score 4):

Upon my own research and help from @Kokodoko it appears that you have to interact with your webpage before audio is allowed. This is why it worked for me when I came from another page, but failed when I refreshed.

The solution: make the user interact.
Unfortunately, there is no true workaround for letting the audio play before the user has interacted. Forcing the user to interact in some way before the audio starts, is the only way to get the audio to work

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I think this behavior was added to prevent annoying audio that a user doesn’t want (from a banner, for example) Especially when opening a new tab.