# Background audio won't play automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to play background music on my website, but the audio file won't autostart when connecting through the URL bar, only when using a link from another website. I am using this inside the website body:

```
<audio src="music.mp3"></audio>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  const audio = document.querySelector("audio");
  audio.volume = 0.3;
  audio.play();
  });
</script>
```

Any suggestions how I could fix this?

Comment: have you checked the source of  the song is correctly given ?

Comment: @nydexx This has been discussed here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235019/why-does-my-javascript-audio-not-work-after-i-refresh-a-page. It's possibly related to Google placing strict policies regarding autoplay of audio - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes. 
Try the same behaviour in other browsers as well.

Comment: @SandrinJoy Yes it's correct and autoplay works, but somehow only when im being redirected to the website.

Comment: how else you wanted it to play ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I had a feeling something like this is causing the problem, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @SandrinJoy I want it to automatically play regardless of the way someone enters the website. As of now it won't play when connecting through the URL bar, only through a redirect from my friends website.

Comment: @nydexx Then probably some file is not loading for ur website. u can check dev tools  console and see any red dialog saying that a particular file is not loaded. Which makes ur script won't run

Comment: It's the way @LakshyaThakur described, autoplay is being blocked by most browsers. Firefox made me realize that, I saw the "blocked" icon next to the URL bar. Brave Browser - my default browser - didn't even bother telling me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoplay attribute into the audio html tag. For example

```
<audio controls autoplay>
  <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Already had a similar approach, still didn't solve the problem.